# Authentification in the DHL-SOAP API

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, soap, dhl

I would like to make a CreateShipmentOrderRequest call, unfortunately I always get back a response "login failed".

I think the authentication that is specified within the XML header is missing:

```
        <soapenv:Header>
            <cis:Authentification>
                <cis:user>2222222222_01</cis:user>
                <cis:signature>pass</cis:signature>
            </cis:Authentification>
        </soapenv:Header>
```

Call:

```
        GVAPI20De service = new GVAPI20De();
        GKV3XAPIServicePortType port = service.getGKVAPISOAP11Port0();
        
        Map<String, Object> req_ctx = ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext();
        req_ctx.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, CvpConstants.DHL_WSDL);
        req_ctx.put("javax.xml.ws.client.connectionTimeout", "60000");

        String userpassword = CvpConstants.DHL_USER + ":" + CvpConstants.DHL_PASSWORD;
        String encodedAuthorization = Base64.encode(userpassword.getBytes());
         
        Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        headers.put("Authorization", Collections.singletonList("Basic " + encodedAuthorization));
        
        req_ctx.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);

        CreateShipmentOrderResponse createShipmentOrder = port.createShipmentOrder(request);
```

How can I add this header to the soap call?

Comment: do you maybe have a typo in `Authentification`?

Comment: No the line of code didn't work, so I removed it.

Comment: Is there a specific library that you use to generate the classes from WSDL ? AXIS2 or CXF or something similar ?

Comment: Yes I used AXIS2

Comment: Did a quick wsdl2java and I can see that the Authentification is created
```    public static final javax.xml.namespace.QName MY_QNAME =
        new javax.xml.namespace.QName(
            "http://dhl.de/webservice/cisbase", "Authentification", "ns1");
    /** field for Authentification */
    protected AuthentificationType localAuthentification;
    public AuthentificationType getAuthentification() {
      return localAuthentification;
    }
``` It should get set from the client , can you use fiddler or something similar to see if the header is set indeed ?

Comment: Unfortunately the header is not filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benjamin Müller gives the answer to your question under the following link.A few objects (actually only names) still have to be adjusted.

[Java WSDL DHL Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52767373/java-wsdl-dhl-classes)

The two lines below the following line must be used, otherwise the authentication will not work.

// overwrite BasicAuth Username and Password

This is the only way DHL will not reject the request with "SECURITY_VIOLATION". All other ways are not approved by DHL and lead to an error message.